# Asp.net Mvc /Oracle/Dapper - Partial name search using Dapper with Oracle

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, dapper

I'm having a little trouble doing partial searches using dapper and oracle.

For example, I want to search for all names that contain phillip in the name. The way I'm doing it only finds if the name is complete, partially it doesn't find anything

```
public IEnumerable<User> FindByName(string name)
    {
        var cn = DbContext.Database.Connection;
        IEnumerable<User> userList;

        var sql = @"SELECT *FROM USER WHERE (:Name IS NULL OR USER.Name LIKE CONCAT(:Name, '%'))";

        var multi = cn.QueryMultiple(sql, new { Name= name});

        userList= multi.Read<User>().ToList();

        return userList;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats the answer, only have to remove the "Tolist()" method.

```
public IEnumerable<User> FindByName(string name)
{
    var cn = DbContext.Database.Connection;

    var sql = @"SELECT *FROM USER WHERE (:Name IS NULL OR USER.Name LIKE CONCAT(:Name, '%'))";

    var multi = cn.QueryMultiple(sql, new { Name= name});

    var userList= multi.Read<User>(); 

    return userList;

}
```